# How to joining two tables with missing rows in the last month?

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, window-functions

I want to join two tables and one is missing a row for each currency group.

Tables:

Transactions in local currency aggregated by month.(transactions table)

```
Date            Currency       spend
2019-01-01       EUR             100
2019-02-01       EUR             200 
2019-03-01       EUR             500
2019-04-01       EUR             214
2019-01-01       JYP            3200
2019-01-01       JYP            1534
2019-02-01       JYP            1534
2019-03-01       JYP            1534
2019-04-01       JYP            1534
```

Exchange Rate by month(exchange_data table)

```
Month            Currency       Average Monthly rate
2019-01-01       EUR            1.2
2019-02-01       EUR            1.3 
2019-03-01       EUR            1.4
2019-01-01       JYP            101
2019-02-01       JYP            102
2019-03-01       JYP            103
2019-01-01       USA            1
2019-02-01       USA            1
2019-03-01       USA            1
```

I want to perform a join to get all the transactions in USD. The problem is that the rate for the current month(2019-04-01) is not available. So all the transactions for the current month return NULL after the join.

I've managed to solve it in R but is there a way to solve it with SQL?
I've been trying to use a window function but without success

```
LAG(rate,1) OVER (PARTITION BY currency ORDER BY month)
```

Solution in R: Assuming that the rate remains constant.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

exchange_previous <- exchange_data[exchange_data$month == floor_date(today(),"month") %m-% months(1),]
exchange_previous$month <- exchange_previous$month %m+% months(1)
exchange_data<-rbind(exchange_data,exchange_previous)

final <- transactions %>%
left_join(exchange_data, by = c("currency" = "name", "floor_date" = "month"))
Then simply multiply
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff postgresql

Comment: Please post desired results or the output of your R code for those Postgres users who do not use R.

Comment: Are all the JPP meant to be JYP? If there is no exchange rate, will you use the one of the previous month?

Comment: @xavier yeah my bad. JPP is JYP. Yeah, the one of the previous month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lateral join but it should look like this:

```
select t.*, ed.average_monthly_rate,
from transactions t left join lateral
     (select ed.*
      from exchange_data ed
      where ed.currency = t.currency and
            ed.month <= t.date
      order by ed.month desc
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) ed
     on 1=1;
```

I'm not sure if you want to divide or multiply by the rate.

Comment: Well played, I didn't think about `ORDER BY month DESC LIMIT 1` in the lateral join.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `LATERAL JOIN` to apply the most recent exchange rate for a currency, like so:

```sql
        SELECT tr.*, rates.rate
          FROM transactions tr
          LEFT JOIN
       LATERAL (SELECT rate
                     -- order rows by date, most recent first
                     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY currency 
                                              ORDER BY d DESC) rn 
                  FROM exchange_data 
                 WHERE currency = tr.currency 
                   -- exchange dates only up until the month of a transaction
                   AND d <= tr.d
             ) rates
            ON rates.rn = 1 -- row for the most recent date
```

`LATERAL JOIN` is similar to `APPLY` in SQL Server, in that it lets you join a resulset using predicates from the outer query.

[Here's a working example on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=46bda7d5682393bf1f2d6d1ecb9da94c).

Comment: Gordon's answer using `ORDER BY month DESC LIMIT 1` is better.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your tables are called Transactions and Exchange, the following code works for MySQL. I guess Postgresql will be similar.

```
select C.date, C.spend/E.Average 
   from Transactions as C, Exchange as E,
      (select A.date, A.Currency, Max(B.Month) as Month 
         from Transactions as A, Exchange as B
         where A.Currency = B.Currency and A.datum >= B.Month
         group by A.date, A.Currency
      ) as D
where C.date = D.date 
   and C.Currency = D.Currency 
   and E.Month = D.Month 
   and C.Currency = E.Currency
order by C.date;
```

The idea behind it is the following: given a date and a currency, you look at table D which is the closest past date for that currency. Once you have that, you can get the exchange you were looking for.